# как работает .minusDays() в Java

Tags: java, localdate

В ходе переписывания исходного кода из учебника столкнулся с такой строкой:

```
date = date.minusDays(today-1); // задать первый день месяца
```

Попытавшись разобраться, как это работает так ни к чему и не пришел. В документации указано, что этот метод "Returns a copy of this LocalDate with the specified number of days subtracted.", то есть если я создаю объект date, и инициализирую его текущей датой (18.9.2018 например), то согласно описания .minusDays() я должен получить 17.9.2018.

В действительности я получаю 1.9.2018, отладчик это подтверждает:

[image: Запуск программы]

[image: Первый шаг, объявление и инициализация переменной today]

[image: Собственно все и свершилось]

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, почему это происходит, а то для меня это сейчас выглядит как магия, а я не люблю магию.

Полный текст программы

```
import java.time.*;

public class CalendarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        int month = date.getMonthValue();
        int today = date.getDayOfMonth();
        date = date.minusDays(today-1);
        DayOfWeek weekday = date.getDayOfWeek();
        int value = weekday.getValue();
        System.out.println("Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun");
        for (int i = 1; i<value; i++) {
            System.out.print("    ");
        }
        while (date.getMonthValue() == month) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", date.getDayOfMonth());
            if (date.getDayOfMonth() == today) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            date = date.plusDays(1);
            if (date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() == 1) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все вроде правильно.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
```

Здесь вы получаете текущую дату - 18.9.2018

```
int today = date.getDayOfMonth();
```

здесь - текущий день месяца по счету, это 18

```
date = date.minusDays(today-1);
```

вычитаете одно из другого  18.9.2018 - (18 дней - 1 день) = 1.09.2018
Т.о. здесь вы не получаете какой то новой даты инициализированной вчерашним днем, а просто проводите математическую операцию по вычитанию параметра в скобках из даты, полученной изначально.